# JavaScript Implicit Returns

Tags: javascript, return, implicit

Implicit Return and concise javascript coding:  Good practice?

Just saw this on CodeAcademy:

```
const volumeOfSphere = (diameter) => {
  return (1/6) * Math.PI * diameter * diameter * diameter;
};

console.log('The volume of a sphere is ' + volumeOfSphere(10) + ' cubic centimeters');
```

According to the course text there, it's better practice to reduce it to this:

```
const volumeOfSphere = diameter => 
  (1/6) * Math.PI * diameter * diameter * diameter;


console.log('The volume of a sphere is ' + volumeOfSphere(10) + ' cubic centimeters');
```

Is this correct?  Isn't it more human readable to have clearly defined parameters, function code blocks etc?  I understand it's important to have concise code, but does this not make it more difficult later to come back and understand?  (This is a simple example, but in practice could be a much larger/convoluted program).

I apologise if this is opinion based.  If flagged as such I'll delete, but was truly interested in this one.

Comment: Kinda opinion-based. I look at it this way. The implicit return of arrow functions helps alot for the readability of calls where you'd pass an anonymous function or a callback, like chained array operations. `const result = data.map( entry => entry.count ).reduce( ( sum, next ) => sum + next, 0 );` This is more readable than the version with inline anonymous functions and shorter than explicitly declaring the functions before the map/reduce.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Shilly.  Not gonna lie - i understand little of what that code does lol.  But, general gist is : use implicit returns where possible, and go with concise as much as possible, readability comes with greater understanding?